# SQL Anywhere 11 (Sybase) with Entity Framework in Visual Studio SP1?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, sqlanywhere

Well, the question is pretty much in the title. I've just installed Visual Studio SP1, and now when I want to import a Entity Model from a database, it doesn't display the SQL Anywhere provider anymore.

Does anyone know if there is a patch or some way to make it work with SP1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a post on the [ASP.NET Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/08/11/third-party-provider-support-for-the-entity-framework-rtm.aspx) that it will be available in Q3-Q4 of 2008. So I guess SP1 does need a new version of SQL Anywhere component.

Did you try to reinstall the integration component just in case?

Comment: Totally off question: What does Q mean? What does it stands for? I saw it a lot lately.

Answer (score 1):

try to install lastest build of SA. And you need to install it after SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and did the following:

1. Control Panel -> Uninstall a program
2. Selected SQL Anywhere 12 - Client an clicked Repair. This made me unable to connect to any database from Sybase Central with an error message about JDBC.
3. Selected SQL Anywhere 12 and clicked Repair.

After that the provider showed up in Visual Studio and I was able to create a new connection to create an Entity Framework model.